# Give different names to app widgets

Tags: android

I implemented three (live, news, music) widgets for a radio application. For each widget I get the application name as the widget name.

How can I give different names to widgets?

E.g. live widget, news widget, music widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `android:label` attribute of the `<receiver>` that you define for each widget in the Manifest.xml file?